# using load_file with dynamically generated path using mysql and python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to load a couple of txt files and insert them into mysql: Here is my code:

```
result = os.listdir("C:/path/")
for x in result:
     db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "Mydatabases#0", "myblog",local_infile=True)
     cursor = db.cursor()
     file1 = os.path.join('path'+x)
cursor.execute("insert into clamp (sample) values (LOAD_FILE(%s),(file1))")
db.commit()
db.close()
```

But I get this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s),(x,))' at line 1")
```

Can nsomeone please tell me what is wrong with my code?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I needed to use:
cursor.execute("insert into clamp (sample) values (LOAD_FILE(%s))", (file1,))